# Appending arrays using method call

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner with JAVA so this question is not making much sense:

> Write a method called append that accepts two integer arrays as
>   parameters and returns a new array that contains the result of
>   appending the second array's values at the end of the first array. For
>   example, if arrays list1 and list2 store {2, 4, 6} and {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>   respectively, the call of append(list1, list2) should return a new
>   array containing {2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. If the call instead had
>   been append(list2, list1), the method would return an array containing
>   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 6}

Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well which part of that you don't understand?

Comment: How to append two arrays being passed to a method.

Comment: At least you could search the same question on stackoverflow. Also check link provided by @thoeni. And if you are beginner in java you could try write some code by yourself and just then post the question. Why other guys should do your home task?

Answer (score 0):

This works, and is fairly self-explanatory:

```
int[] append(int[] ary1, int[] ary2) {
    int[] arrayOut = new int[ary1.length + ary2.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<ary1.length; i++) {
        arrayOut[i] = ary1[i];
    }
    for(int i = ary1.length; i< (ary1.length + ary2.length); i++) {
        arrayOut[i] = ary2[i - ary1.length];
    }
    return arrayOut;
}
```

Comment: What second iteration will do if first array length more than second array length?

Comment: Good point,... I've corrected the answer.

Comment: still not correct. In second for loop you initialize i with length of first array. How you wanna get first element of second array? At least try run your code before posting.

Comment: okay okay, now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int[] append(int[]... a) {
    return Stream.of(a)
        .flatMapToInt(IntStream::of)
        .toArray();
}
```

and

```
int[] a = {2, 4, 6};
int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(append(a, b)));
```

result:

```
[2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You can also append three or more arrays.

Answer (score 0):

package iran;

public class ExampleTest {

//https://telegram.me/javalike

```
public int[] append(int[] array1, int[] array2) {

    int array[] = new int[array1.length + array2.length];
    int counter = 0;
    int flage = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i < array1.length) {
            array[i] = array1[counter];
            counter++;
        } else {
            if (flage == 0) {
                counter = 0;
                flage = 1;
            }
            array[i] = array2[counter];
            counter++;
        }
    }

    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExampleTest t = new ExampleTest();

    int a[] = { 2, 4, 6 };
    int b[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int c[] = t.append(b, a);
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {

        System.out.print(c[i] + " ");
    }

}
```

}

result:
1 2 3 4 5 2 4 6

Comment: How flage variable is working in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the best performance, you can use native methods like `System.arraycopy()` instead of a loop.

```
public static int[] append(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    int[] merged = new int[a.length + b.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, merged, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, merged, a.length, b.length);
    return merged;
}
```

But not coming up with your own "manual" solution could defeat the purpose of this assignment.